# I would like to automate this - copy pasting data from one excel to the other when structure in second excel is not same as the first

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to copy paste data from one Excel sheet to the other, but the structure is not the same. I am looking for an easy solution (preferably minimum to no coding involved) to solve a repetitive task. Copy pasting for 700 sheets and 30 columns per sheet will take me long time so I am reaching out to the experts here. I am using the Desktop Excel version 16.51 in my Mac (but Windows solution will also do).

For example - In sheet 1

```
Name : XYZ

Address : ABC

Phone number : 300

Notes : PQR
```

And in sheet 2 (the left side columns are present here, only need to paste the data)

```
Address : ____(need to paste ABC here)

Name : ___(need to paste XYZ here)

Notes : ___(need to paste PQR)
```

See how phone number column is not present in sheet 2 so that data won't get copied over

Can someone tell me if it is possible to automate something like this step-by-step?

Comment: If your source sheet can have the formulas added in the same order as the target sheet, you could do that and make your copy and pasting faster. This is something that could be done with a macro. Try recording yourself doing these steps with the Macro Recorder and then start adjusting it as needed. Show what you have tried, and issues you have ran into so the community can give you feedback, this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Sure @WyattShipman I will try it!

Comment: If you don't want use vba code, your solution is very hard. For example you can try in this way. In the cells of the sheet 2 (need to past ABC here) write + and after go in sheet1 and click the cell with ABC content. You repeat this step foreach cells you need. In your case 700 sheets for 30 columns.

Comment: Title says you want to copy/paste whenever there's a difference; but 2nd last line says opposite as far as I can tell (i.e. difference => no copy and paste...) which is it?